# Clickable background container of SVG element in Gatsby

Tags: css, reactjs, svg, gatsby

I have a concept for the hero element on the website but have the problem with overlying SVG.
[image]

Grid cells are generated flex items and there is a background under each of them. Each grid cell has hover effect so it reveals the underlying background, as on the attached picture.

I have a problem with the SVG element which is lines and dots on front of all elements. The whole SVG prevents from the grid cells being hovered so I can hover only on the edge ones.

I build it with Gatsby, here's the code:

````
import Logo from "../../../assets/logos.svg"

/* Some standard react ... */

<div className={"hero__content-container"}>
  <div className={"hero__content-image-box"}>
    <div className={"hero__content-image"}></div>
    <Logo className={"hero__content-logo"} />
    <div className={"hero__content-boxes"} ref={targetRef}>
      {generateBoxes(dimensions.width, dimensions.height)}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

And the css:

.hero__content-container {
  padding: 5rem 0;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

  @media (min-width: $lg) {
    padding: 5rem 10rem;
    height: 100%;
  }
}

.hero__content-image-box {
  height: 10rem;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0.5rem;

  @media (min-width: $lg) {
    height: 50rem;
    width: 90rem;
  }
}

.hero__content-image {
  background-image: url("./../../img/hero_code.svg");
  background-size: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: scale(2);

  @media (min-width: $lg) {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

.hero__content-logo {
  display: block;
  height: 62%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: -80%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.hero__content-boxes {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border-left: 1px solid $default-black;
  border-top: 1px solid $default-black;
}

.hero__content-box {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  background-color: $white;
  box-sizing: border-box;

  &--hovered {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
}```

How can I make this SVG element to be transparent and make background able to hover?
````

Comment: I don't want to attach listener to SVG, rather make the svg element to be only the lines and dots so the grid below it might be hovered. Now, even if the svg has 'transparent' background, I can't hover over the grid because it's under the <svg> element.

Comment: Misread your Q, sorry for that, I have a similar setup with an `SVG` design grid with rulers, doc center point, 10x10px grid which I use as a `<body>` **background image**. The point with html elements is (even with `background: transparent`), they do occupy a square/rectangle of space on your screen. If you only want to interact with the cells, make the cell backgrounds (almost) transparent so you can still see the SVG. In my page with grid I usually make a `:hover`ed element background temporarily opaque. You simply can't have both cells and SVG occupy the same space

Comment: Here is a quick and dirty [Codepen](https://codepen.io/renevanderlende/pen/VwLrQao) I just created to show what I mean. Shows the background grid and a few elements with interaction. Let me know if this method works for you, then I will create an 'official' answer, whooo. (just saw: the SVG has responsive ruler `font-size` too, forgot all about it...)

Comment: Just tested something similar to your setup: add `pointer-events: none` to the element showing the grid (`.hero__content-image`) and you will be able to click 'through' the `SVG`. [Codepen 2](https://codepen.io/renevanderlende/pen/WNvXMMX), same as previous pen, but now the `SVG` on top. Solution was easier than I thought...

Comment: Thank you very much for such comprehensive answer. `pointer-events` does the trick for me. Thank you.

Comment: I have added a proper answer to your question, please review and accept so others can benefit from this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest solution is adding `pointer-events: none` to the element showing the grid `(.hero__content-image)` and keep using the `SVG` as an image overlaying the grid cells.

However, there is a catch: If you want to (temporarily) remove the `SVG` from the users' view, you need to set its `height: 0` and `width: 0`, because while invisible it still occupies its original space and therefore blocks `pointer-events`.

Another solution would be to use the `SVG` as `background-image` of the container holding the grid cell. This way you don't have to keep track of pointer events. The catch here obviously is, that grid cell contents may hide parts of the `SVG`.

It entirely depends on your requirements which of the two solutions works best.

For your convenience I have created 2 examples on codepen showing the solutions. Both examples show an `SVG` grid with a few generic html elements. The grid can be toggled visible/invisible with simple vanilla javascript.

**Example 1 on [codepen](https://codepen.io/renevanderlende/pen/WNvXMMX) and snippet** using `pointer-events: none` located in `#designGrid[design*="1"] {...}`. When you remove `#designGrid[design*="0"] { width: 0; height: 0 }` you will notice that you can toggle only once, after which the html elements are no longer accessible, blocked by the hidden `SVG`.

```js
function toggleElementAttrib(s,a) { 
    var elem = document.getElementById(s);
    if (elem.getAttribute(a)=='1') elem.setAttribute(a,'0'); else elem.setAttribute(a,'1');
}
```

```css
body        { position: relative }
h1:hover    { background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.1)}

/* show viewport grid with rulers */
#designGrid { position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; height: 100%; width: 100% }

#designGrid[design*="0"] { width: 0; height: 0 }
#designGrid[design*="1"] {
    pointer-events       : none;
    background-origin    : border-box;
    background-position  : 0 0;
    background-size      : cover;
    background-repeat    : no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
        /* Quite large SVG, multi-purpose grid (8px,10px,16px) with rulers and center viewport dot. So you know...;) */
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cpattern id='pattern8' width='8' height='8' patternUnits='userSpaceOnUse'%3E%3Cpath d='M 8 0 L 0 0 0 8' fill='none' stroke='gray' stroke-width='0.5' /%3E%3C/pattern%3E%3Cpattern id='pattern80' width='80' height='80' patternUnits='userSpaceOnUse'%3E%3Crect width='80' height='80' fill='url(%23pattern8)' /%3E%3Cpath d='M 80 0 L 0 0 0 80' fill='none' stroke='gray' stroke-width='1' /%3E%3C/pattern%3E%3Cpattern id='pattern10' width='10' height='10' patternUnits='userSpaceOnUse'%3E%3Cpath d='M 10 0 L 0 0 0 10' fill='none' stroke='gray' stroke-width='0.5' /%3E%3C/pattern%3E%3Cpattern id='pattern100' width='100' height='100' patternUnits='userSpaceOnUse'%3E%3Crect width='100' height='100' fill='url(%23pattern10)' /%3E%3Cpath d='M 100 0 L 0 0 0 100' fill='none' stroke='gray' stroke-width='1' /%3E%3C/pattern%3E%3Cpattern id='pattern16' width='16' height='16' patternUnits='userSpaceOnUse'%3E%3Cpath d='M 16 0 L 0 0 0 16' fill='none' stroke='gray' stroke-width='0.5' /%3E%3C/pattern%3E%3Cpattern id='pattern160' width='160' height='160' patternUnits='userSpaceOnUse'%3E%3Crect width='160' height='160' fill='url(%23pattern16)' /%3E%3Cpath d='M 160 0 L 0 0 0 160' fill='none' stroke='gray' stroke-width='1' /%3E%3C/pattern%3E%3C!-- horizontal ruler --%3E%3Cg id='ruler-h' style=' fill: none; fill-opacity: 1; fill-rule: nonzero; stroke: RoyalBlue; stroke-width: 1; stroke-opacity: 1; stroke-linecap:butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-dashoffset: 0'%3E%3Cline x1= '0' y1='0' x2='100%25' y2='0'/%3E%3C!-- transform() only used for a little optic correction (tested Firefox 68+, zoom in 300%25) --%3E%3Cpath transform='translate(0.15 0)' d='M 10,0 10, 5 M 20,0 20,10 M 30,0 30,10 M 40,0 40,10 M 50,0 50,20 M 60,0 60,10 M 70,0 70,10 M 80,0 80,10 M 90,0 90,10 M 100,0 100,30 M 110,0 110,10 M 120,0 120,10 M 130,0 130,10 M 140,0 140,10 M 150,0 150,20 M 160,0 160,10 M 170,0 170,10 M 180,0 180,10 M 190,0 190,10 M 200,0 200,30 M 210,0 210,10 M 220,0 220,10 M 230,0 230,10 M 240,0 240,10 M 250,0 250,20 M 260,0 260,10 M 270,0 270,10 M 280,0 280,10 M 290,0 290,10 M 300,0 300,30 M 310,0 310,10 M 320,0 320,10 M 330,0 330,10 M 340,0 340,10 M 350,0 350,20 M 360,0 360,10 M 370,0 370,10 M 380,0 380,10 M 390,0 390,10 M 400,0 400,30 M 410,0 410,10 M 420,0 420,10 M 430,0 430,10 M 440,0 440,10 M 450,0 450,20 M 460,0 460,10 M 470,0 470,10 M 480,0 480,10 M 490,0 490,10 M 500,0 500,30 M 510,0 510,10 M 520,0 520,10 M 530,0 530,10 M 540,0 540,10 M 550,0 550,20 M 560,0 560,10 M 570,0 570,10 M 580,0 580,10 M 590,0 590,10 M 600,0 600,30 M 610,0 610,10 M 620,0 620,10 M 630,0 630,10 M 640,0 640,10 M 650,0 650,20 M 660,0 660,10 M 670,0 670,10 M 680,0 680,10 M 690,0 690,10 M 700,0 700,30 M 710,0 710,10 M 720,0 720,10 M 730,0 730,10 M 740,0 740,10 M 750,0 750,20 M 760,0 760,10 M 770,0 770,10 M 780,0 780,10 M 790,0 790,10 M 800,0 800,30 M 810,0 810,10 M 820,0 820,10 M 830,0 830,10 M 840,0 840,10 M 850,0 850,20 M 860,0 860,10 M 870,0 870,10 M 880,0 880,10 M 890,0 890,10 M 900,0 900,30 M 910,0 910,10 M 920,0 920,10 M 930,0 930,10 M 940,0 940,10 M 950,0 950,20 M 960,0 960,10 M 970,0 970,10 M 980,0 980,10 M 990,0 990,10 M 1000,0 1000,30 M 1010,0 1010,10 M 1020,0 1020,10 M 1030,0 1030,10 M 1040,0 1040,10 M 1050,0 1050,20 M 1060,0 1060,10 M 1070,0 1070,10 M 1080,0 1080,10 M 1090,0 1090,10 M 1100,0 1100,30 M 1110,0 1110,10 M 1120,0 1120,10 M 1130,0 1130,10 M 1140,0 1140,10 M 1150,0 1150,20 M 1160,0 1160,10 M 1170,0 1170,10 M 1180,0 1180,10 M 1190,0 1190,10 M 1200,0 1200,30 M 1210,0 1210,10 M 1220,0 1220,10 M 1230,0 1230,10 M 1240,0 1240,10 M 1250,0 1250,20 M 1260,0 1260,10 M 1270,0 1270,10 M 1280,0 1280,10 M 1290,0 1290,10 M 1300,0 1300,30 M 1310,0 1310,10 M 1320,0 1320,10 M 1330,0 1330,10 M 1340,0 1340,10 M 1350,0 1350,20 M 1360,0 1360,10 M 1370,0 1370,10 M 1380,0 1380,10 M 1390,0 1390,10 M 1400,0 1400,30 M 1410,0 1410,10 M 1420,0 1420,10 M 1430,0 1430,10 M 1440,0 1440,10 M 1450,0 1450,20 M 1460,0 1460,10 M 1470,0 1470,10 M 1480,0 1480,10 M 1490,0 1490,10 M 1500,0 1500,30 M 1510,0 1510,10 M 1520,0 1520,10 M 1530,0 1530,10 M 1540,0 1540,10 M 1550,0 1550,20 M 1560,0 1560,10 M 1570,0 1570,10 M 1580,0 1580,10 M 1590,0 1590,10 M 1600,0 1600,30 M 1610,0 1610,10 M 1620,0 1620,10 M 1630,0 1630,10 M 1640,0 1640,10 M 1650,0 1650,20 M 1660,0 1660,10 M 1670,0 1670,10 M 1680,0 1680,10 M 1690,0 1690,10 M 1700,0 1700,30 M 1710,0 1710,10 M 1720,0 1720,10 M 1730,0 1730,10 M 1740,0 1740,10 M 1750,0 1750,20 M 1760,0 1760,10 M 1770,0 1770,10 M 1780,0 1780,10 M 1790,0 1790,10 M 1800,0 1800,30 M 1810,0 1810,10 M 1820,0 1820,10 M 1830,0 1830,10 M 1840,0 1840,10 M 1850,0 1850,20 M 1860,0 1860,10 M 1870,0 1870,10 M 1880,0 1880,10 M 1890,0 1890,10 M 1900,0 1900,30 M 1910,0 1910,10 M 1920,0 1920,10 M 1930,0 1930,10 M 1940,0 1940,10 M 1950,0 1950,20 M 1960,0 1960,10 M 1970,0 1970,10 M 1980,0 1980,10 M 1990,0 1990,10 M 2000,0 2000,30 M 2010,0 2010,10 M 2020,0 2020,10 M 2030,0 2030,10 M 2040,0 2040,10 M 2050,0 2050,20 M 2060,0 2060,10 M 2070,0 2070,10 M 2080,0 2080,10 M 2090,0 2090,10 M 2100,0 2100,30 M 2110,0 2110,10 M 2120,0 2120,10 M 2130,0 2130,10 M 2140,0 2140,10 M 2150,0 2150,20 M 2160,0 2160,10 M 2170,0 2170,10 M 2180,0 2180,10 M 2190,0 2190,10 M 2200,0 2200,30 M 2210,0 2210,10 M 2220,0 2220,10 M 2230,0 2230,10 M 2240,0 2240,10 M 2250,0 2250,20 M 2260,0 2260,10 M 2270,0 2270,10 M 2280,0 2280,10 M 2290,0 2290,10 M 2300,0 2300,30 M 2310,0 2310,10 M 2320,0 2320,10 M 2330,0 2330,10 M 2340,0 2340,10 M 2350,0 2350,20 M 2360,0 2360,10 M 2370,0 2370,10 M 2380,0 2380,10 M 2390,0 2390,10 M 2400,0 2400,30 M 2410,0 2410,10 M 2420,0 2420,10 M 2430,0 2430,10 M 2440,0 2440,10 M 2450,0 2450,20 M 2460,0 2460,10 M 2470,0 2470,10 M 2480,0 2480,10 M 2490,0 2490,10 M 2500,0 2500,30 M 2510,0 2510,10 M 2520,0 2520,10 M 2530,0 2530,10 M 2540,0 2540,10 M 2550,0 2550,20 M 2560,0 2560,10 M 2570,0 2570,10 M 2580,0 2580,10 M 2590,0 2590,10 M 2600,0 2600,30 M 2610,0 2610,10 M 2620,0 2620,10 M 2630,0 2630,10 M 2640,0 2640,10 M 2650,0 2650,20 M 2660,0 2660,10 M 2670,0 2670,10 M 2680,0 2680,10 M 2690,0 2690,10 M 2700,0 2700,30 M 2710,0 2710,10 M 2720,0 2720,10 M 2730,0 2730,10 M 2740,0 2740,10 M 2750,0 2750,20 M 2760,0 2760,10 M 2770,0 2770,10 M 2780,0 2780,10 M 2790,0 2790,10 M 2800,0 2800,30 M 2810,0 2810,10 M 2820,0 2820,10 M 2830,0 2830,10 M 2840,0 2840,10 M 2850,0 2850,20 M 2860,0 2860,10 M 2870,0 2870,10 M 2880,0 2880,10 M 2890,0 2890,10 M 2900,0 2900,30 M 2910,0 2910,10 M 2920,0 2920,10 M 2930,0 2930,10 M 2940,0 2940,10 M 2950,0 2950,20 M 2960,0 2960,10 M 2970,0 2970,10 M 2980,0 2980,10 M 2990,0 2990,10 M 3000,0 3000,30 M 3010,0 3010,10 M 3020,0 3020,10 M 3030,0 3030,10 M 3040,0 3040,10 M 3050,0 3050,20 M 3060,0 3060,10 M 3070,0 3070,10 M 3080,0 3080,10 M 3090,0 3090,10 M 3100,0 3100,30' /%3E%3C!-- todo: upto 6500 --%3E%3C/g%3E%3C!-- vertical ruler --%3E%3Cg id='ruler-v' style=' fill: none; fill-opacity: 1; fill-rule: nonzero; stroke: RoyalBlue; stroke-width: 1; stroke-opacity: 1; stroke-linecap:butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-dashoffset: 0'%3E%3Cline x1= '0' y1='0' x2='0' y2='100%25'/%3E%3Cpath transform='translate(0 0.2)' d='M 0, 10 5, 10 M 0, 20 10, 20 M 0, 30 10, 30 M 0, 40 10, 40 M 0, 50 20, 50 M 0, 60 10, 60 M 0, 70 10, 70 M 0, 80 10, 80 M 0, 90 10, 90 M 0, 100 30, 100 M 0, 110 10,110 M 0, 120 10, 120 M 0, 130 10, 130 M 0, 140 10, 140 M 0, 150 20, 150 M 0, 160 10, 160 M 0, 170 10, 170 M 0, 180 10,180 M 0, 190 10, 190 M 0, 200 30, 200 M 0, 210 10,210 M 0, 220 10, 220 M 0, 230 10, 230 M 0, 240 10, 240 M 0, 250 20, 250 M 0, 260 10, 260 M 0, 270 10, 270 M 0, 280 10,280 M 0, 290 10, 290 M 0, 300 30, 300 M 0, 310 10,310 M 0, 320 10, 320 M 0, 330 10, 330 M 0, 340 10, 340 M 0, 350 20, 350 M 0, 360 10, 360 M 0, 370 10, 370 M 0, 380 10,380 M 0, 390 10, 390 M 0, 400 30, 400 M 0, 410 10,410 M 0, 420 10, 420 M 0, 430 10, 430 M 0, 440 10, 440 M 0, 450 20, 450 M 0, 460 10, 460 M 0, 470 10, 470 M 0, 480 10,480 M 0, 490 10, 490 M 0, 500 30, 500 M 0, 510 10,510 M 0, 520 10, 520 M 0, 530 10, 530 M 0, 540 10, 540 M 0, 550 20, 550 M 0, 560 10, 560 M 0, 570 10, 570 M 0, 580 10,580 M 0, 590 10, 590 M 0, 600 30, 600 M 0, 610 10,610 M 0, 620 10, 620 M 0, 630 10, 630 M 0, 640 10, 640 M 0, 650 20, 650 M 0, 660 10, 660 M 0, 670 10, 670 M 0, 680 10,680 M 0, 690 10, 690 M 0, 700 30, 700 M 0, 710 10,710 M 0, 720 10, 720 M 0, 730 10, 730 M 0, 740 10, 740 M 0, 750 20, 750 M 0, 760 10, 760 M 0, 770 10, 770 M 0, 780 10,780 M 0, 790 10, 790 M 0, 800 30, 800 M 0, 810 10,810 M 0, 820 10, 820 M 0, 830 10, 830 M 0, 840 10, 840 M 0, 850 20, 850 M 0, 860 10, 860 M 0, 870 10, 870 M 0, 880 10,880 M 0, 890 10, 890 M 0, 900 30, 900 M 0, 910 10,910 M 0, 920 10, 920 M 0, 930 10, 930 M 0, 940 10, 940 M 0, 950 20, 950 M 0, 960 10, 960 M 0, 970 10, 970 M 0, 980 10,980 M 0, 990 10, 990 M 0,1000 30,1000 M 0,1010 10,1010 M 0,1020 10,1020 M 0,1030 10,1030 M 0,1040 10,1040 M 0,1050 20,1050 M 0,1060 10,1060 M 0,1070 10,1070 M 0,1080 10,1080 M 0,1090 10,1090 M 0,1100 30,1100 M 0,1110 10,1110 M 0,1120 10,1120 M 0,1130 10,1130 M 0,1140 10,1140 M 0,1150 20,1150 M 0,1160 10,1160 M 0,1170 10,1170 M 0,1180 10,1180 M 0,1190 10,1190 M 0,1200 30,1200 M 0,1210 10,1210 M 0,1220 10,1220 M 0,1230 10,1230 M 0,1240 10,1240 M 0,1250 20,1250 M 0,1260 10,1260 M 0,1270 10,1270 M 0,1280 10,1280 M 0,1290 10,1290 M 0,1300 30,1300 M 0,1310 10,1310 M 0,1320 10,1320 M 0,1330 10,1330 M 0,1340 10,1340 M 0,1350 20,1350 M 0,1360 10,1360 M 0,1370 10,1370 M 0,1380 10,1380 M 0,1390 10,1390 M 0,1400 30,1400 M 0,1410 10,1410 M 0,1420 10,1420 M 0,1430 10,1430 M 0,1440 10,1440 M 0,1450 20,1450 M 0,1460 10,1460 M 0,1470 10,1470 M 0,1480 10,1480 M 0,1490 10,1490 M 0,1500 30,1500 M 0,1510 10,1510 M 0,1520 10,1520 M 0,1530 10,1530 M 0,1540 10,1540 M 0,1550 20,1550 M 0,1560 10,1560 M 0,1570 10,1570 M 0,1580 10,1580 M 0,1590 10,1590 M 0,1600 30,1600 M 0,1610 10,1610 M 0,1620 10,1620 M 0,1630 10,1630 M 0,1640 10,1640 M 0,1650 20,1650 M 0,1660 10,1660 M 0,1670 10,1670 M 0,1680 10,1680 M 0,1690 10,1690 M 0,1700 30,1700 M 0,1710 10,1710 M 0,1720 10,1720 M 0,1730 10,1730 M 0,1740 10,1740 M 0,1750 20,1750 M 0,1760 10,1760 M 0,1770 10,1770 M 0,1780 10,1780 M 0,1790 10,1790 M 0,1800 30,1800 M 0,1810 10,1810 M 0,1820 10,1820 M 0,1830 10,1830 M 0,1840 10,1840 M 0,1850 20,1850 M 0,1860 10,1860 M 0,1870 10,1870 M 0,1880 10,1880 M 0,1890 10,1890 M 0,1900 30,1900 M 0,1910 10,1910 M 0,1920 10,1920 M 0,1930 10,1930 M 0,1940 10,1940 M 0,1950 20,1950 M 0,1960 10,1960 M 0,1970 10,1970 M 0,1980 10,1980 M 0,1990 10,1990 M 0,2000 30,2000 M 0,2010 10,2010 M 0,2020 10,2020 M 0,2030 10,2030 M 0,2040 10,2040 M 0,2050 20,2050 M 0,2060 10,2060 M 0,2070 10,2070 M 0,2080 10,2080 M 0,2090 10,2090 M 0,2100 30,2100 M 0,2110 10,2110 M 0,2120 10,2120 M 0,2130 10,2130 M 0,2140 10,2140 M 0,2150 20,2150 M 0,2160 10,2160 M 0,2170 10,2170 M 0,2180 10,2180 M 0,2190 10,2190 M 0,2200 30,2200 M 0,2210 10,2210 M 0,2220 10,2220 M 0,2230 10,2230 M 0,2240 10,2240 M 0,2250 20,2250 M 0,2260 10,2260 M 0,2270 10,2270 M 0,2280 10,2280 M 0,2290 10,2290 M 0,2300 30,2300 M 0,2310 10,2310 M 0,2320 10,2320 M 0,2330 10,2330 M 0,2340 10,2340 M 0,2350 20,2350 M 0,2360 10,2360 M 0,2370 10,2370 M 0,2380 10,2380 M 0,2390 10,2390 M 0,2400 30,2400 M 0,2410 10,2410 M 0,2420 10,2420 M 0,2430 10,2430 M 0,2440 10,2440 M 0,2450 20,2450 M 0,2460 10,2460 M 0,2470 10,2470 M 0,2480 10,2480 M 0,2490 10,2490 M 0,2500 30,2500 M 0,2510 10,2510 M 0,2520 10,2520 M 0,2530 10,2530 M 0,2540 10,2540 M 0,2550 20,2550 M 0,2560 10,2560 M 0,2570 10,2570 M 0,2580 10,2580 M 0,2590 10,2590 M 0,2600 30,2600 M 0,2610 10,2610 M 0,2620 10,2620 M 0,2630 10,2630 M 0,2640 10,2640 M 0,2650 20,2650 M 0,2660 10,2660 M 0,2670 10,2670 M 0,2680 10,2680 M 0,2690 10,2690 M 0,2700 30,2700 M 0,2710 10,2710 M 0,2720 10,2720 M 0,2730 10,2730 M 0,2740 10,2740 M 0,2750 20,2750 M 0,2760 10,2760 M 0,2770 10,2770 M 0,2780 10,2780 M 0,2790 10,2790 M 0,2800 30,2800 M 0,2810 10,2810 M 0,2820 10,2820 M 0,2830 10,2830 M 0,2840 10,2840 M 0,2850 20,2850 M 0,2860 10,2860 M 0,2870 10,2870 M 0,2880 10,2880 M 0,2890 10,2890 M 0,2900 30,2900 M 0,2910 10,2910 M 0,2920 10,2920 M 0,2930 10,2930 M 0,2940 10,2940 M 0,2950 20,2950 M 0,2960 10,2960 M 0,2970 10,2970 M 0,2980 10,2980 M 0,2990 10,2990 M 0,3000 30,3000 M 0,3010 10,3010 M 0,3020 10,3020 M 0,3030 10,3030 M 0,3040 10,3040 M 0,3050 20,3050 M 0,3060 10,3060 M 0,3070 10,3070 M 0,3080 10,3080 M 0,2990 10,3090 M 0,3100 30,3100' /%3E%3C!-- todo: upto 4000 --%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg id='ruler-text-h' style='fill-rule:nonzero; fill-opacity:1; fill: RoyalBlue; stroke:none; stroke-width:1; stroke-linecap:butt; stroke-linejoin:miter; stroke-miterlimit:4; stroke-dasharray:none; stroke-dashoffset:0; stroke-opacity:1; text-anchor: middle; font-family: Consolas,Arial,monospace; font-weight: normal; font-size : calc(0.625vmin + 0.5rem); text-shadow: .1px .1px .2px hsla(0,0%25,15%25,.35), -.1px -.1px .2px hsla(0,0%25,15%25,.25);'%3E%3C!-- horizontal text --%3E%3Ctext x= '122' y='30'%3E100%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x= '222' y='30'%3E200%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x= '322' y='30'%3E300%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x= '422' y='30'%3E400%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x= '522' y='30'%3E500%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x= '622' y='30'%3E600%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x= '722' y='30'%3E700%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x= '822' y='30'%3E800%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x= '922' y='30'%3E900%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='1022' y='30'%3E1000%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='1122' y='30'%3E1100%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='1222' y='30'%3E1200%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='1322' y='30'%3E1300%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='1422' y='30'%3E1400%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='1522' y='30'%3E1500%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='1622' y='30'%3E1600%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='1722' y='30'%3E1700%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='1822' y='30'%3E1800%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='1922' y='30'%3E1900%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='2022' y='30'%3E2000%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='2122' y='30'%3E2100%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='2222' y='30'%3E2200%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='2322' y='30'%3E2300%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='2422' y='30'%3E2400%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='2522' y='30'%3E2500%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='2622' y='30'%3E2600%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='2722' y='30'%3E2700%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='2822' y='30'%3E2800%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='2922' y='30'%3E2900%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='3022' y='30'%3E3000%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='3122' y='30'%3E3100%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='3222' y='30'%3E3200%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='3322' y='30'%3E3300%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='3422' y='30'%3E3400%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='3522' y='30'%3E3500%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='3622' y='30'%3E3600%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='3722' y='30'%3E3700%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='3822' y='30'%3E3800%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='3922' y='30'%3E3900%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='4022' y='30'%3E4000%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='4122' y='30'%3E4100%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='4222' y='30'%3E4200%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='4322' y='30'%3E4300%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='4422' y='30'%3E4400%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='4522' y='30'%3E4500%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='4622' y='30'%3E4600%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='4722' y='30'%3E4700%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='4822' y='30'%3E4800%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='4922' y='30'%3E4900%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='5022' y='30'%3E5000%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='5122' y='30'%3E5100%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='5222' y='30'%3E5200%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='5322' y='30'%3E5300%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='5422' y='30'%3E5400%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='5522' y='30'%3E5500%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='5622' y='30'%3E5600%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='5722' y='30'%3E5700%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='5822' y='30'%3E5800%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='5922' y='30'%3E5900%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='6022' y='30'%3E6000%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='6122' y='30'%3E6100%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='6222' y='30'%3E6200%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='6322' y='30'%3E6300%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='6422' y='30'%3E6400%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='6522' y='30'%3E6500%3C/text%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg id='ruler-text-v' style='fill-rule:nonzero; fill-opacity:1; fill: RoyalBlue; stroke:none; stroke-width:1; stroke-linecap:butt; stroke-linejoin:miter; stroke-miterlimit:4; stroke-dasharray:none; stroke-dashoffset:0; stroke-opacity:1; text-anchor: middle; font-family: Consolas,Arial,monospace; font-weight: normal; font-size : calc(0.625vmin + 0.5rem); text-shadow: .1px .1px .2px hsla(0,0%25,15%25,.35), -.1px -.1px .2px hsla(0,0%25,15%25,.25);'%3E%3C!-- vertical text --%3E%3Ctext x='32' y= '120' %3E100%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='32' y= '220' %3E200%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='32' y= '320' %3E300%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='32' y= '420' %3E400%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='32' y= '520' %3E500%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='32' y= '620' %3E600%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='32' y= '720' %3E700%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='32' y= '820' %3E800%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='32' y= '920' %3E900%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='32' y='1020' %3E1000%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='32' y='1120' %3E1100%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='32' y='1220' %3E1200%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='32' y='1320' %3E1300%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='32' y='1420' %3E1400%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='32' y='1520' %3E1500%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='32' y='1620' %3E1600%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='32' y='1720' %3E1700%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='32' y='1820' %3E1800%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='32' y='1920' %3E1900%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='32' y='2020' %3E2000%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='32' y='2120' %3E2100%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='32' y='2220' %3E2200%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='32' y='2320' %3E2300%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='32' y='2420' %3E2400%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='32' y='2520' %3E2500%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='32' y='2620' %3E2600%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='32' y='2720' %3E2700%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='32' y='2820' %3E2800%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='32' y='2920' %3E2900%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='32' y='3020' %3E3000%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='32' y='3120' %3E3100%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='32' y='3220' %3E3200%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='32' y='3320' %3E3300%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='32' y='3420' %3E3400%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='32' y='3520' %3E3500%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='32' y='3620' %3E3600%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='32' y='3720' %3E3700%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='32' y='3820' %3E3800%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='32' y='3920' %3E3900%3C/text%3E%3Ctext x='32' y='4020' %3E4000%3C/text%3E%3C/g%3E%3C!-- screen centers --%3E%3Cg id='doc-crosshair' style='stroke: RoyalBlue; stroke-width: 1; stroke-opacity: 1'%3E%3Cline x1= '0%25' y1='50%25' x2='100%25' y2= '50%25'/%3E%3Cline x1='50%25' y1= '0' x2= '50%25' y2='100%25'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg id='doc-center'%3E%3Ccircle cx='50%25' cy='50%25' r='3' style='stroke: RoyalBlue; fill: Red'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/defs%3E%3Csymbol id='svg-grid8'%3E%3Crect width='100%25' height='100%25' fill='url(%23pattern80)'/%3E%3C/symbol%3E%3Csymbol id='svg-grid10'%3E%3Crect width='100%25' height='100%25' fill='url(%23pattern100)'/%3E%3C/symbol%3E%3Csymbol id='svg-grid16'%3E%3Crect width='100%25' height='100%25' fill='url(%23pattern160)'/%3E%3C/symbol%3E%3Csymbol id='svg-ruler-h'%3E%3Cuse xlink:href='%23ruler-h'/%3E%3Cuse xlink:href='%23ruler-text-h'/%3E%3C/symbol%3E%3Csymbol id='svg-ruler-v'%3E%3Cuse xlink:href='%23ruler-v'/%3E%3Cuse xlink:href='%23ruler-text-v'/%3E%3C/symbol%3E%3Csymbol id='svg-ruler-full'%3E%3Cuse xlink:href='%23ruler-h'/%3E%3Cuse xlink:href='%23ruler-text-h'/%3E%3Cuse xlink:href='%23ruler-v'/%3E%3Cuse xlink:href='%23ruler-text-v'/%3E%3C/symbol%3E%3Csymbol id='svg-ruler-grid8-full'%3E%3Cuse xlink:href='%23svg-grid8'/%3E%3Cuse xlink:href='%23svg-ruler-full'/%3E%3C/symbol%3E%3Csymbol id='svg-ruler-grid10-full'%3E%3Cuse xlink:href='%23svg-grid10'/%3E%3Cuse xlink:href='%23svg-ruler-full'/%3E%3C/symbol%3E%3Csymbol id='svg-ruler-grid16-full'%3E%3Cuse xlink:href='%23svg-grid16'/%3E%3Cuse xlink:href='%23svg-ruler-full'/%3E%3C/symbol%3E%3Csymbol id='svg-element-center'%3E%3Cuse xlink:href='%23doc-crosshair'/%3E%3Cuse xlink:href='%23doc-center'/%3E%3C/symbol%3E%3C!-- default for use as 'background-image' --%3E%3Cuse xlink:href='%23svg-ruler-grid10-full'/%3E%3Cuse xlink:href='%23svg-element-center'/%3E%3C/svg%3E%0A");
}
```

```html
<h1>
        some text on top if grid
    </h1>
    <button>button too</button>
    <button onclick="toggleElementAttrib('designGrid','design')">toggle grid</button>
 
    <div id="designGrid" design="1"></div>
```

**Example 2 on [codepen](https://codepen.io/renevanderlende/pen/VwLrQao) only**, using the `SVG` as `<body>` `background-image`. Same layout and html elements, but as you will notice, no special actions are required to access the html elements whether the grid is visible or not.